# Graph library to handle big dataset

Tags: java, bigdata, guava, graph-algorithm, hashset

I'm looking for a Java library able to handle a big dataset, in the best way possible in terms of memory and performance.

Here are my requirements. This is an early description of the contents of one of the nodes the final graph will have to contain :

```
public final class CategoryNode {
    private int    nbPages;
    private int    nbSubCats;
    private String label;

    CategoryNode(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    /** Getters/Setters **/
    public int getNbPages() {
        return nbPages;
    }
    public void setNbPages(int nbPages) {
        this.nbPages = nbPages;
    }
    //
    public int getNbSubCats() {
        return nbSubCats;
    }
    public void setNbSubCats(int nbSubCats) {
        this.nbSubCats = nbSubCats;
    }
    //
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return label.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((CategoryNode) o).getLabel().equals(label);
    }
}
```

The final graph will contain at least 1.8 million nodes, and at least 200 million edges. The graph is a directed non-valued graph, and doesn't allow parallel edges. The graph will be stored entirely in RAM.

The two main operations will be the following :

**1)** Retrieve the nodes by their label

**2)** Retrieve successors and predecessors of each node

If possible, for the operation 1), I would like to use a built-in component of the library and not an external set which is very expensive in terms of memory.

I have already tried to :

**A)** Use only native java collections (**HashSet** and **HashMap**), with not much success : the memory structure created is too big and the access times are not optimal.

**B)** Use **Koloboke** (for the side index) and **Guava Graphs**. Still a lot of memory used, and I would prefer not having to add too much dependencies to my project.

**C)** Use **Guava Graphs** only. The ImmutableMap was not really what I was looking for, it was not the optimal set for this problem.

I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: You might consider using [Netflix Graph](https://github.com/Netflix/netflix-graph) which is a compact, in-memory java library.

Comment: I think @BenManes's suggestion is worth pursuing. But if it doesn't work for you, you could also consider [Cassovary](https://github.com/twitter/cassovary), with the caveats that it's written in Scala and at time of writing it looks unmaintained.

Comment: If neither of these options with for you, though, then sadly I can only think of two other now difficult options that may work: (1) create a custom implementation of the Guava `Graph|ValueGraph|Network` interface that uses memory-efficient data structure(s) under the hood, or (2) look into Hadoop, Spark or something else in the Big Data ecosystem.

Comment: For req. "1) Retrieve the nodes by their label", have you considered using CQEngine's [`WrappingPersistence`](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://raw.githubusercontent.com/npgall/cqengine/master/documentation/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/cqengine/persistence/wrapping/WrappingPersistence.html) over your graph's `nodes()`?

Comment: Alternatively, JGraphT now has a memory-efficient graph implementation called `FastutilMapGraph` within its relatively new "jgrapht-opt" library: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-opt/latest/index.html